# How to make the switch cases inside foreach loops faster and enhance the performance

Tags: c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

The goal is to read and process the data inside various files spread in different directories, my program is in C#.
The path of all the directories and the line numbers to process of the file in each directory is stored in a Tuple that contains 4 interger values.

Item1 and item2 of Tuple makes the path of a directory ,
Item3 and Item4 carries the line numbers from the text file which need to be processed by the logic inside switch cases.
I am reading the file in a datatable and using Item3 and Item4 to move between the lines in pairs and using switch cases which are checking for the relevant data of the file.

There are maximum 380 different fields per line pair to be check (between Item3 and Item4) which represent the lines, for eg:- (1,39),(40,96)..and so on.

The problem is the switch cases are taking too long to process currently for processing 1000 line pairs spread in a file with 100000 lines
the program is taking somewhere between 8-12 mins. This file is just a sample data and the file can have a maximum of 10000 pairs and a maximum of 3.8 mill lines, but this is on the extreme end.

Is there any way to speed this up or anything to speed this up please. Here is my sample code.

```
public void check()
{
    //comingFromOtherClass is List<Tuple<int,int,int,int>>
    MasterList = comingFromOtherClass();
    var BreakingTheMasteList = MasterList.ToLookup(x => Tuple.Create(x.Item1, x.Item2), y => Tuple.Create(y.Item3, y.Item4)); 
    Parallel.ForEach(BreakingTheMasteList , items =>
    {
        string FilePath = someDir +"\\"+items.Item1 +"\\"+items.Item2;
        List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> LineNos = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
        LineNos.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(items.Item3, items.Item4));
        foreach(var itm in LineNos)
        {
            int startingLine = itm.Key;
            int endLine = itm.Value;
            for(int i = startingLine; i < endLine; i++)
            {
                DataTable dt = MethodToCreateDatatale(FilePath);
                string X = dt.Rows[i].Field<string>(0);
                string Y = dt.Rows[i].Field<string>(1);
                aPredefinedEnum EN;
                bool s = Enum.TryParse(X, EN);
                var Z = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(EN), X);if (!s)
                {
                    EN = aPredefinedEnum.DfVal;
                }
                switch(EN)
                {
                    case aPredefinedEnum.Q0:
                    //case 1 :- logic
                    //all the logic is in 'NOT' therefore if the condition is not satisfied only then the logic will be triggered else it breaks and goes to the next case.
                    if (!(Enumerable.Range(0, 2).Contains(Int16.Parse(Y))))
                    {
                        //error logging
                        //capture the value of startLine and endLine
                        //or throw some info error
                        //all the cases are checking different ranges.
                    }
                    break;
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    case aPredefinedEnum.Q380:
                    //case 380 :- logic

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `the switch cases are taking too long to process` you didn't post that code so it's impossible to help. The code you posted processes each file in a separate thread already. To speed things up you need to speed up the code that's missing

Comment: I'd expect `MethodToCreateDatatale` to be slow because it uses inefficient parsing. Loading all the data into a DataTable is definitely *in*efficient. Doing so inside a loop will parse the same file over and over, even though the data hasn't changed (I assume).

Comment: Added the sample code which is inside the case and yes the data inside the data table doesn't change. I don't know if this information helps but I am using File.ReadAllLines(filePath)  to read the data into the data table.

Comment: You didn't post any code, just comments. `the data inside the data table doesn't change` then that alone makes the loop `endLine` times slower. Have you tried loading the table *outside* the loop? Using a DataTable and using `ReadAllLines` is inefficient as well.  If you know which lines you want, you can only these lines. If you use `ReadLines` you'll get an `IEnumerable<string>` that returns one line at a time. You can use that with `Where` to only load the lines you want, eg `.Where((line,idx)=> lineNumbers.Contains(idx))`